# Visual Studio 2015 enterprise edition cant install

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

When I try to install VS 2015 enterprise edition it keeps failing at: Microsoft Build Tools 14.0 (x86). After a while it says setup failed anf fatal error during installation. I tried googling the error but without success. The error log is not very helpful either.

OS: windows 10 (64 bits)

Someone knows how to fix this?

The log was too big to post here so I uploaded the bottom part to pastebin:
http://pastebin.com/74QuurHv

Comment: share the log files from the failed setup

Comment: I added a link to pastebin because the log file was way too big. This is not the whole log but only the bottom part

Comment: you only get the generic error 0x80070643 (ERROR_INSTALL_FAILURE) with no details. Ask this Microsoft in their forums at MSDN: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/home?forum=vssetup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apperently my Anti-Virus was the problem. When I turned it off my installation worked.

Answer (score 6):

Being on a corporate computer I was unable to disable the antivirus however I was able to get around this issue by doing the following:

First I tried to install Build Tools 2015 separately and found I did not have a high enough version of .Net installed.

I installed .NET 4.5.2
I installed Build Tools 2015
I went into Uninstall/Change programs and select Change on Visual Studio 2015
From the Visual Studio menu I selected "Repair"

Comment: This worked for me, but I just installed .NET 4.5.2 and then ran the install again. So I am past this error point..

Answer (score 0):

Please update the system with all the latest updates given by windows officially and they try it. Microsoft will give some updates which will solve some common issues.

Comment: I already checked for updates but my system is already up to date

Comment: Microsoft Build Tools Language Resources 14.0 (x86) is also failing and blocking Visual Studio 14 install.

Answer (score 0):

Use Microsoft Build Tools 14 or 15 version this separately installs the build tools. Once this is done start 2015 installation as usual.